# Issue displaying mnist training images in console

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, mnist

Heres my code from tutorial.

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
print(tf.__version__)

#import the MNIST dataset 
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

#load training and testing sets
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(training_images[0])

print(training_labels[0])
print(training_images[0])
```

The issue is, when I run it I get [this output in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkieQ.png) the image is cut in half right down the middle. For reference its supposed to look more like

[image]

you can see the image displays properly. I'm sure its just some dumb setting I'm missing.

I've tried messing with some of the properties for the command prompt window like window/buffer width, but nothing works so far.

Comment: It's probably just due to the width of your console. If you resize it by making it fullscreen, it should be fine. Make sure one line fits in the resized console.

Comment: @ParthShah nah, I ran the code on my machine in full screen, seems linewidth output is capped at 80 characters or something. Since I couldn't find an option to change it, I submitted my answer, saving the output to a textfile.

Comment: @RolandDeschain yeah, numpy setting looks like

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing for you to do is to save the output into a txt file in a formated way.
For example:

```
np.savetxt("test.txt", training_images[0], fmt='%8.2f')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's two print loops. You can try something of this sort:

```
t_images = training_images[0].tolist()

for image in t_images:
    for value in image:
        print('%4d'%(value), end='')

    print()
```

The `%4d` pads with 4 spaces.

This is how it looks:
[image: sample output]